# How do I configure my machine so that I can log in with a fingerprint?

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I setup fingerprint authentication using this howto: http://lauri.vosandi.eu/blog/?p=1069

After this, I can log in using fingerprint and password, but I want to log in using only fingerprint (and using password if finger does not work).

Can you please help me?

Thank you,

Daniel Costa

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that you are using Ubuntu 12.10.

Install the `libpam-fprintd` and `printd` packages from universe.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpam-fprintd fprintd
```

You should see the following.

```
$ grep fprint /etc/pam.d/common-auth 
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so
```

Enroll your fingerprint.

```
$ fprintd-enroll
```